# Test pixel alignment in raster images

Tags: raster, gdal, landsat, alignment, rapideye

I want to test if two raster images for the same scene taken in different moments are aligned. I would like to do this automatically as I will be working with a lot of scene pairs. The process would not need to be perfect I would like to spot obvious miss-alignments (i.e. more than 2 pixels) and flag them for manual inspection.

Is there a standard way to do so?

I am using python + GDAL

Comment: I am using python + GDAL

Comment: gdalinfo should give you, among many other things, the origin, cell size and extent (corner coordinates).  If those match, your rasters are aligned.

Comment: @JKelly That is not necessary true. In satellites like Rapideye, scenes can carry errors even when the metadata is correct. This can be spotted manually using Control Ground Points, however I am dealing with many images (around 8000+) so it would be desirable to have a first filter to spot these errors.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for automated image registration.

I would use something like ENVI (Automatic Image to Image Registration) or ERDAS Imagine (Autosync) to perform tie point generation which you can then inspect.

For an opensource option, check out [RSGISLib](http://www.rsgislib.org/rsgislib_imageregistration.html) which is available as a [package](https://anaconda.org/rios/rsgislib) via [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/quick.html) (Win64, OSX and Linux)

The GDAL project has this [functionality](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/alg/gdalmatching.cpp) as well, but it only seems to be exposed via the C++ API, not via a command line tool or the python bindings.